# Swift 4 Not decoding JSON optional properly

Tags: json, swift

Swift noob here.

I'm trying to follow the App Development With Swift book and am running into trouble with decoding JSON data from the NASA API as given in the examples. Here's the code I'm trying to use:

```
struct PhotoInfo: Codable {  
    var title: String  
    var description: String  
    var url: URL  
    var copyright: String?  

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {  
        case title  
        case description = "explanation"  
        case url  
        case copyright  
    }  

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {  
        let valueContainer = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)  
        self.title = try valueContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: CodingKeys.title)  
        self.description = try valueContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: CodingKeys.description)  
        self.url = try valueContainer.decode(URL.self, forKey: CodingKeys.url)  
        self.copyright = try valueContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: CodingKeys.copyright)  
    }  
}  


func fetchPhotoInfo(completion: @escaping (PhotoInfo?) -> Void) {  
    let baseURL = URL(string: "https:/  
    let query: [String: String] = [  
        "api_key": "yN3**0scRWo12gCa25TWBcfp3rcuAnoeqwbpvLPn",  
        "date": "2011-07-13"  
    ]  
    let url = baseURL.withQueries(query)!  
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in  
        let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()  
        if let data = data,  
            let photoInfo = try? jsonDecoder.decode(PhotoInfo.self, from: data) {  
            print(data)  
            completion(photoInfo)  
        } else {  
            print("Either no data was returned, or data was not properly decoded.")  
            completion(nil)  
        }  
    }  
    task.resume()  
}
```

When I remove the copyright code from the PhotoInfo struct, it decodes the JSON and prints the data (line 36). Otherwise, it doesn't deserialize it. Is there a way I can troubleshoot why this is happening? Does it have something to do with the optional?

Comment: please post error logs in case of copyright code.

Comment: @technerd unfortunately there are no visible error logs, it just fails to decode. If it's throwing something somewhere, I'm not sure how to surface that.

Comment: Check my answer.it may help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If copyright is optional , then you can make use of `decodeIfPresent`.

```
self.copyright = try valueContainer.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: CodingKeys.copyright)
```

Comment: That worked like a charm. Do you happen to know why off the top of your head? This is something I'd like to learn from.

Answer (score -2):

***EDIT:*** Updated per @matt's comments.

technerd's answer is probably best, but I faced the same problem and dealt with it by changing `try` to `try?`. That's how it was presented in previous exercises, anyway. However, as @matt points out, this doesn't deal with the possibility that the copyright information isn't simply missing, but in fact something other than what was expected. Using `try?` in tandem with an `if let` statement provides at least basic feedback.

Comment: Problem with that is, if there’s an error, you just fail silently and you’ve thrown the error info away. It’s the worst possible strategy. Basically, you never “dealt with it”. You just closed your eyes and wished it away.

Comment: @matt: True, but as the book has yet to deal with proper error handling at that point, is it a problem? The `copyright` property is an optional, and (not shown in the code provided by OP) the label which uses that value is simply hidden if the property is nil. If this app simply displays these properties, and it's expected that the API doesn't provide the copyright value half the time (with no consequences for it missing), is it still critical to "deal" with the error, rather than move on silently? I'm also new to Swift, so I'm asking in earnest.

Comment: The optionality of the property (the key might be missing) and the possibility of an error (the property is present but something is wrong with it, e.g. wrong type) are two different things. `try valueContainer.decodeIfPresent` covers both.

Comment: What I personally do if I’m sure of my ground is `try!`. That way if I’m wrong I am forced to face the error. I can’t recommend that to everyone or in every case, obviously, but at least I’m not hiding the error from myself.  Or, if you do use `try?`, also use `if let` so you can learn of the error if there is one (though you are still throwing away the valuable error info).

Comment: @matt Got it! The book uses the same `try?` technique just pages earlier, never bothering to bring up `decodeIfPresent`. Here's hoping your books are much better than the official ones. :D

Comment: They’re not, at least not in this regard. I don’t get into the nitty gritty of JSON decoding best practices.

Comment: @matt Something to be said for honesty. ;)

Comment: Also note that `init(from:)` throws. So if you just say `try` you’ll hear about the error just fine. But if you say `try?` you swallow it silently.

Comment: @matt Maybe this is from where more of the confusion arises.Despite throwing, the function which calls the `init` never handles the error in the book's exercise, so there's actually no immediately apparent error if following the guide as written.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181301/discussion-between-matt-and-cartoonchess).