# Decoding optional values in JSON - Swift 4

Tags: swift, option-type, jsondecoder

I've read read many tutorials and searched for answers here on SO;

[Decoding Nested JSON with Optional Values Swift 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52377458/decoding-nested-json-with-optional-values-swift-4)

[Swift 4 Not decoding JSON optional properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47566292/swift-4-not-decoding-json-optional-properly)

Decoding optionals doesn't seem problematic using below code. Obviously I'm doing something wrong, but what is it!?

Part of my code:

```
struct ProductInfo: Codable {
    var name: String?
    let images: [Image]
    var ingredients: String?
    let origin: [Origin]
    let producer: Producer

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name = "Artikelbenamning"
        case images = "Bilder"
        case ingredients = "Ingrediensforteckning"
        case origin = "Tillverkningslander"
        case producer = "Varumarke"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        name = try? values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .name)!
        images = try values.decodeIfPresent([Image].self, forKey: .images)!
        ingredients = try? values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .ingredients)!
        origin = try values.decodeIfPresent([Origin].self, forKey: .origin)!
        producer = try values.decodeIfPresent(Producer.self, forKey: .producer)!
    }
}
```

The app queries a products database. Following json is returned when a product doesn't exist. App crashes when trying to decode nil name ("Artikelbenamning in json) in init(from:).

```
{
    "GTIN": null,
    "TillverkarensArtikelnummer": null,
    "Artikelbenamning": null,
    "RegleratProduktnamn": null,
    "Forvaringsinstruktion": null,
    "Variabelmattsindikator": false,
    "Bruttovikt": null,
    "Bredd": null,
    "Djup": null,
    "Hojd": null,
    "Returemballage": false,
    "FarligtGodsKod": null,
    "FarligtGodsKlass": null,
    "FarligtGodsForpackningsgrupp": null,
    "GPCKod": null,
    "GiltigFROM": null,
    "Publiceringsdatum": null,
    "FakturerbarEnhet": false,
    "Slutdatum": null,
    "GiltighetsdatumPris": null,
    "Tillganglighetstidpunkt": null,
    "SistaTillganglighetstidpunkt": null,
    "SkapadDatum": null,
    "SenastAndradDatum": null,
    "Flampunkt": null,
    "KodBegransadMangd": null,
    "OfficiellTransportbenamning": null,
    "OspecificeradTransportbenamning": null,
    "TunnelrestriktionADR": null,
    "KlassificeringskodFarligtgods": null,
    "Transportkategori": null,
    "Konsumentartikel": false,
    "BestallningsbarForpackning": false,
    "RabattOlaglig": null,
    "Garantiloptid": 0,
    "Konsumentdatum": null,
    "Tjanst": false,
    "Sasongsindikator": null,
    "Engangskop": null,
    "AntalReturnerbaraEnheter": 0,
    "Staplingsriktning": null,
    "Staplingstyp": null,
    "MaxTransportTemperatur": 0.0,
    "MinTransportTemperatur": 0.0,
    "Anvandningsinstruktioner": null,
    "HallbarhetEfterOppning": 0,
    "Riskfras": null,
    "KodlistutgivareRiskfras": null,
    "Klassificeringssystem": null,
    "FarligtGodsBegransadMangd": null,
    "FarligtGodsOvrigInfo": null,
    "FarligtGodsSarbestammelser": null,
    "T3495_Artikelavisering": null,
    "T4032_TypAvUtgangsdatum": null,
    "T3742_ForstaLeveransdatum": null,
    "Undervarumarke": null,
    "Niva": null,
    "Produktbladslank": null,
    "KompletterandeProduktklass": null,
    "T4200_AllmänPubliceringstidpunkt": null,
    "T3848_TypAvTryckkanslighet": null,
    "Varningsetiketter": [],
    "Sasongskoder": [],
    "Produktklasser": [],
    "MaskinellMarkningar": [],
    "Bilder": [],
    "ReferenserTillAndraArtiklar": [],
    "MSRKritierier": [],
    "Kravspecifikationer": [],
    "Receptlinks": [],
    "Allergener": [],
    "Markningar": [],
    "Ingredienser": [],
    "Tillagningsinformation": [],
    "Tillverkningslander": [],
    "Naringsinfo": [],
    "Serveringsforslag": [],
    "Diettyper": [],
    "Tillagningsmetoder": [],
    "Farger": [],
    "VillkorForsaljning": [],
    "Varumarke": {
        "Varumarke": null,
        "AgareGLN": null,
        "AgareNamn": null,
        "Tillverkare": {
            "Namn": null,
            "EAN": null
        }
    },
    "Nettoinnehall": [],
    "Kontakter": [],
    "Faroangivelser": [],
    "Sakerhet": [],
    "Forpackningar": [],
    "Tillsatser": [],
    "Substanser": [],
    "Fangstzoner": [],
    "Marknadsbudskap": null,
    "KortMarknadsbudskap": null,
    "Komponenter": null
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API `decodeIfPresent` is pointless in this case because the key **does** exist.

An *existing* key with `null` value and a *missing* key are two different situations.

And never force unwrap in the `init(from decoder` method.

There are two options:

1. Delete the entire `init` method then the optional struct members handle the `null` values.
2. Use regular `decode` and ignore the error

   ```
   name = try? values.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Sorry, newbie here, what exactly do you mean bt your option 1?

Comment: I mean what I wrote: Delete the `init(from decoder` method. The protocol extension provides a synthesized one.

Comment: Ok. I will try and get back to you.

Comment: Curious, can you tell me why it crashed?

Comment: Because `try?` returns an optional and if there is is no string (or one of the other types) and you force unwrap it, it crashes. Please read the third paragraph once more.